# Caption background color does not extend the width of the table In Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a strange formatting issue. I have an MVC application that uses Bootstrap 4.  When I specify the width of the table using a `style="width:xx%"` attribute on the  declaration, the background color of the caption row only extends across part of the table. If I don't specify the width, the background color works perfectly. I've attached a snip that displays an example of a table using auto width, and a table where I've set the width to 70%.

The container is "container-fluid body-content input-group-sm". The _layout.cshtml includes the following style tags, though I'm only referencing the "table mytable" style in this example, as you'll see in the View source below.

```css
body {
  padding-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

tr {
  line-height: 10px;
  min-height: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  /*padding: 0 !important;*/
}

td {
  padding: 5px;
}

.table th,
.table td {
  padding: 5px 8px;
}

.mytable>tbody>tr>td,
.mytable>tbody>tr>th,
.mytable>tfoot>tr>td,
.mytable>tfoot>tr>th,
.mytable>thead>tr>td,
.mytable>thead>tr>th {
  padding: 4px;
}

.mytable {
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 2px;
  width: auto;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.mytable caption {
  caption-side: top;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  color: #333;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  border-color: rgb( 204, 204, 204);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div style="white-space:nowrap">
  <h4>Test Page</h4>
  <table class="table mytable">
    <caption>My Caption - Table 1</caption>
    <tr>
      <th style="width:30%">Heading 1:</th>
      <td>
        Row 1
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Heading 2:</th>
      <td>
        Row 2
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br />
  <br />
  <table class="table mytable" style="width:70%">
    <caption>My Caption - Table 2</caption>
    <tr>
      <th style="width:30%">Heading 3:</th>
      <td>
        Row 3
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Heading 4:</th>
      <td>
        Row 4
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

I'm absolutely no expert on style sheets, so if this is a newbie level question, I apologize.  I've done quite a bit of googling to try and understand this, but have come up empty.  Any hints on why this is happening, and suggestions on how to correct it would be most appreciated. Thanks!

[image: Example of short caption background]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `display: inline-block` from `.mytable` class.

```css
body {
  padding-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

tr {
  line-height: 10px;
  min-height: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  /*padding: 0 !important;*/
}

td {
  padding: 5px;
}

.table th,
.table td {
  padding: 5px 8px;
}

.mytable>tbody>tr>td,
.mytable>tbody>tr>th,
.mytable>tfoot>tr>td,
.mytable>tfoot>tr>th,
.mytable>thead>tr>td,
.mytable>thead>tr>th {
  padding: 4px;
}

.mytable {
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);
  margin-right: 2px;
  width: auto;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.mytable caption {
  caption-side: top;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  color: #333;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  border-color: rgb( 204, 204, 204);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div style="white-space:nowrap">
  <h4>Test Page</h4>
  <table class="table mytable">
    <caption>My Caption - Table 1</caption>
    <tr>
      <th style="width:30%">Heading 1:</th>
      <td>
        Row 1
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Heading 2:</th>
      <td>
        Row 2
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br />
  <br />
  <table class="table mytable" style="width:70%">
    <caption>My Caption - Table 2</caption>
    <tr>
      <th style="width:30%">Heading 3:</th>
      <td>
        Row 3
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Heading 4:</th>
      <td>
        Row 4
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: That was the solution.  Thanks!